# Mysql fulltext boolean ignore phrase

Tags: mysql, boolean, full-text-search

I'm trying to come up with a mysql boolean search that matches "monkey" but ignores / doesn't take into account an matches of "monkey business".

Something like the following is the general idea but it negates the value. I need it to not match rows with "monkey business" unless they also have "monkey" without "business" after it elsewhere in the text.

```
SELECT * FROM table
MATCH (title) against ('+monkey ~"monkey business"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance for any help you can give! I realise this could be done with better search engines, at the moment fulltext is all I can use.

Comment: You might have luck asking this on dba.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it works:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MATCH (title) against ('+monkey' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND NOT MATCH (title) against ('+"monkey business"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

p.s I also tried the boolean negation operator:

```
AND MATCH (title) against ('-"monkey business"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after. Rows that match "monkey business" should still match "monkey" as long as "monkey" appears elsewhere in the same row without a trailing "business". So "This is monkey business" shouldn't be matched, but "monkey business is for monkey men". Thanks for your reply!